# Wordpress multidomains and subfolders

Tags: multisite, installation

Is it possible to have wordpress installed in subfolder (e.g.: example.com/wodpress-installation ) as multisite / folders, and have the folders as example.com/foo or example.com/bar or it must be example.com/wordpressinstallations/foo or example.com/wordpressinstallations/bar

Answer (score 0):

According to [this codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#WordPress_Settings_Requirements), it is not possible to install WordPress in a sub-directory *and* use the Sub-domain install.

However, you should be able to install WordPress in a sub-directory (example.com/foo) and use the other sub-directories for your networked sites (example.com/bar).

Also, check out [this entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) for more info on installing WordPress in a separate directory and using it to power your root.